# "P" symbol for notation of a plane in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

My professor uses this semi-cursive P for the notation of a plane in LaTeX, though I cannot seem to locate it. I used Detexify, but no luck. Any ideas?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @downvoter, why down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `$\mathcal{P}$` by typing `\mathcal{P}`